# What do you call someone who is conducting surveillance

Tags: single-word-requests

I initially assumed **surveillor**, but apparently that isn't a word. Is there a word for such a person that derives from *surveillance*? Meaning it starts with the root *"survei-"*

> His job is to conduct surveillance at the mall. He is a _____.

Comment: [surveillant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surveillant)

Comment: It probably depends on whether the person is watching CCTV in a little room or following people around shops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **surveillant** (as mentioned in the comments) or **spy**.

> surveillant: One that exercises surveillance.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=surveillant))

> spy: One who secretly keeps watch on another or others.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spy))

Comment: That's reasonable, but what about the good old American 'gumshoe'?

Comment: @Tuffy, if you think that *gumshoe* is a good alternative answer, why don't you post it as such? (I don't think that it is, because it is limited to certain kinds of surveillance, but then the same is true of a couple of other answers, which did receive some upvotes.)

Answer (score 2):

Even though it doesn't start with "surveil-," I will go with  ***[static] security officer/[guard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+security+guard%2Cbeen+a+security+guard%2Csecurity+guard+in%2Csecurity+guard+at%2Cthe+security+guard+at%2Cthe+security+guard+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20security%20guard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20a%20security%20guard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecurity%20guard%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecurity%20guard%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20security%20guard%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20security%20guard%20in%3B%2Cc0)*** and ***[loss prevention officer](http://work.chron.com/loss-prevention-officer-job-description-18079.html) or specialist or detective***.

> **Careers in Mall Security: Job Options and Requirements**
>
> Static Positions
>
> **Static mall security positions are primarily surveillance positions that require the officer to monitor the property from one location,
> usually by watching video feeds from security cameras.** Static
> officers then communicate their findings to mobile officers, who
> investigate and address the situation. Static security officers may
> also be called loss prevention specialists or loss prevention
> detectives; mall or store management may hire these professionals to
> develop strategies to minimize loss by theft, and train other security
> officers in applying those strategies. [Study.com](http://study.com/articles/Careers_in_Mall_Security_Job_Options_and_Requirements.html)

Comment: Guards probably must watch to protect, but those doing surveillance are charged only with watching.

Comment: +1 for *security guard*. "Watchman" is another possibility.

Comment: @deadrat  A surveillant is charged with watching over a person, group, etc., especially one in custody or under suspicion. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surveillance

Comment: @Elian That's right.  Surveillance is watching.  This is different from guarding.

Comment: @deadrat But "surveillant" is not a job but a duty/assignment. For example, a police officer will be assigned by their chief to act as a surveillant over a suspect or criminal, i.e. to keep close watch on them.

Comment: @deadrat https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+a+surveillant%2Cis+a+surveillant%2Cis+the+surveillant%2Ca+surveillant+at%2Ca+surveillant+in%2Cthe+surveillant+at%2Cthe+surveillant+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: @Elian Surveillance is a job or an assignment, one different from the job of guarding.  A surveillant is a person, one whose job is different from but overlapping that of a guard. You seem to keep agreeing with me in what I take to be comments of disagreement.  I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you think the ngram plot shows.

Comment: @deadrat Sure, but "surveillant" is not a job, at least in English http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surveillant. A static security officer position encompasses surveillance monitoring. I wish you could only prove me wrong coming up with facts like a "surveillant" job description or anything...

Comment: @deadrat https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22smartphone+jaywalker%22&oq=%22smartphone+jaywalker%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3741.23050.0.23498.25.24.1.0.0.0.321.4914.0j4j15j2.21.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..8.17.3696.0.OmF6UYlRs6Q#q=%22surveillant%22++%22monitoring%22+%22malll%22

Comment: Je ne parle pas français.

Comment: @deadrat My bad. Then, this might help... http://www.wordreference.com/fren/agent%20de%20surveillance

Comment: @Elian I think I finally understand.  The French word *surveillant* means a guard, but the English word *surveillant* means someone who conducts surveillance, in other words, a watcher.

Comment: @deadrat Indeed, a "surveillant" in French is someone who guards, i.e. who keeps a protecting, supervising, or restraining watch or control over people such as prisoners, students, etc. An "agent de surveillance," on the other hand, is someone, like a security guard/officer, who keeps a supervising watch over a place such as a mall, store, factory, etc.

Comment: @deadrat Actually, a "surveillant" in English would be someone like a police officer or Government Secret Service operative who keeps intent watch over a suspect, potential terrorist or group of terrorists, gang, etc. http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/surveillance And so, I would say the term doesn't really fit the context of mall security monitoring...

Comment: This is the right answer in so far as people who conduct surveillance usually have job titles that are not derivatives of *surveillance*. Some such term would fit well the OP's sample sentence, but it does not answer the general question that the OP is asking.

Comment: Shopping malls pay people to identify and *stop* crime and disorder; TV hidden camera shows pay people to film without intervening.

Answer (score 2):

"Surveillor" should be a valid word, for example I just came across this excellent usage:

> There's a strong physiological basis for privacy. Biologist Peter Watts makes the point that a desire for privacy is innate: mammals in particular don't respond well to surveillance. We consider it a physical threat because animals in the natural world are surveilled by predators. Surveillance makes us feel like prey, just as it makes the surveillors act like predators.

From *Data and Goliath* by Bruce Schneier, p. 126-127

Answer (score 1):

**Watchdog** is used at times, for instance `UN watchdog is keeping an eye on facilities`.

Another example here:  http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/nov/06/un-watchdog-confirms-mustard-gas-attack-in-syria